# How to convert all IP address lists to decimal numbers in Pandas

Tags: pandas

There is huge list data, how to convert all IP addresses to decimal numbers in pandas and merge with the value of the second column

```
   import pandas as pd
   filename = "/Users/sda/Desktop/file"
   pdd = pd.read_csv(filename,header=None,sep='|',error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False,skiprows=[0],
              names=['Name','Code','Ipv', 'Ip','Range','Date', 'Category'])
   pd.options.display.max_columns = None
   k = pdd[pdd['Ipv'].str.contains("ipv4") & pdd['Ip'].str.contains('[0-9]')]
   print(k[['Ip','Range','Code']])
```

my output:

```
        Ip         Range    Code
     2.16.0.0      524288   EU
     200.109.100.0 1024     RU
     200.109.102.0 1024     RU
```

only need to get the decimal value of the first IP address with the same country code and range number.merge with the value of the second column only

```
       IP         range code
    3362612224    2028  RU
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, Considering the dataframe name of the output is `df`,  something like this:

```
import socket, struct

def ip2int(ip):
    """
    Convert an IP string to int
    """
    packedIP = socket.inet_aton(ip)
    return struct.unpack("!L", packedIP)[0]

df['ip_int'] = df.Ip.apply(ip2int)
df['range_sum']=df.groupby(['Code'])['Range'].transform('sum')
df[df.Code.duplicated(keep='last')]

               Ip  Range Code      ip_int  range_sum
 1  200.109.100.0   1024   RU  3362612224       2048
```

Comment: use this function under this line?
k = pdd [pdd ['Ipv'] .str.contains ("ipv4") & pdd ['Ip']. str.contains ('[0 - 9]')]

Comment: @warezers this is after you have the output. `df = k[['Ip','Range','Code']]`

Comment: got some error:
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  k['range_sum']=k.groupby(['Code'])['Range'].transform('sum')

Comment: @warezers that is because k is a slice try assigning k to a dataframe , `df = k[['Ip','Range','Code']]` , also before that execute this line `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None` after that use the code. :)

Comment: Now it's not an error and if I get the output of this value  only?
# df[df.Code.duplicated(keep='last')])
print(df[['ip_int','range_sum','Code']])

Comment: @warezers i didnt get you this time , if you omit the `df[df.Code.duplicated(keep='last')]) ` you will get all the values and not just the first occurance

Comment: like to get output only this `33554432 79116144 FR`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186989/discussion-between-anky-91-and-warezers).